# ItemID using ChipNavigationBar Android -> kotlin

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, menuitem, android-bottomnav

I am Using this inside `onCreate()`. I created four fragments for home, like, search and profile. I got this ChipNavgation from https://github.com/ismaeldivita/chip-navigation-bar

```
lateinit var btm_nav : ChipNavigationBar
    btm_nav = findViewById(R.id.btm_nav)
            val homeFragment = HomeFragment()
            val favoriteFragment = FavoriteFragment()
            val searchFragment = SearchFragment()
            val profileFragment = ProfileFragment()
    
            setCurrentFragment(homeFragment)
            btm_nav.setOnItemSelectedListener({
                when (it.itemId) {
                    R.id.home -> setCurrentFragment(homeFragment)
                    R.id.fav -> setCurrentFragment(favoriteFragment)
                    R.id.search -> setCurrentFragment(searchFragment)
                    R.id.profile -> setCurrentFragment(profileFragment)
    
                }
    
            })
```

But this code isn't running, could not access the **ItemID**.
error -> *Unresolved reference: itemId*
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cPLdN.png)

see the image

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`setOnItemSelectedListener` method callback is itself returning the `id` of the menu item. `it` is the `id` of the menu item. Change `it.itemId` with `it`

```
btm_nav.setOnItemSelectedListener({
            when (it) {
                R.id.home -> setCurrentFragment(homeFragment)
                R.id.fav -> setCurrentFragment(favoriteFragment)
                R.id.search -> setCurrentFragment(searchFragment)
                R.id.profile -> setCurrentFragment(profileFragment)

            }

})
```

Comment: Yes. It worked!